# Got black screen when recording screen by x11grab device

Tags: ffmpeg, xvfb

I'm trying to record video from a firefox run by `xvfb-run` but it always output nothing in the video file except black screen.

Here's what I did:

start a firefox, open google.com:

```
$ xvfb-run firefox https://google.com
```

Then it will use the default display server number 99. I can see the display information by command `xdpyinfo -display :99`.

A screenshot works very well by command:

```
$ xwd -root -silent -display :99.0 | xwdtopnm |pnmtojpeg > screen.jpg
```

Start using ffmpeg to record a video:

```
$ ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :99.0 out.mpg
```

When I play the video file `out.mpg`, there's black screen all the time.

Is there any parameter I missed?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thanks. Moved to superuser.com: [Got black screen when recording screen from xvfb by ffmpeg x11grab device](http://superuser.com/questions/727352/got-black-screen-when-recording-screen-from-xvfb-by-ffmpeg-x11grab-device)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have fixed this bug but if you haven't let me help out because I ran into same issue. Here's a solution (I'm running on Fedora 30):

Your need to Configuring `Xorg` as the default `GNOME` session. On your terminal open your `custom.conf` by typing the this command `sudo nano /etc/gdm/custom.conf` and uncomment `WaylandEnable=false` if it's commented but must be set to `false`

Then, on the `[daemon]` section just under `WaylandEnable=false` add this line `DefaultSession=gnome-xorg.desktop` and save the file. Then try running your Screen Recorder program again.
Congratulations.

However, if nano command is not working please try installing it by running the command
`sudo dnf install nano` or `sudo apt-get install nano` which ever works for you.

Comment: this question has been moved to https://superuser.com/questions/727352/got-black-screen-when-recording-screen-from-xvfb-by-ffmpeg-x11grab-device